# server not accessible from outside the local network

Tags: networking, router, ip, firewall, port-forwarding

I'm not able to access my server from outside the local network and I think the problem might be with the router settings or my ISP.

In the local network I can access my server (nextcloud on raspbian lite) from my local IP, the external IP and by using a noip domain. Everything seems to work. However, if I am on my phone and use LTE, it is always timing out. I forwarded Port 80 and 443 to my pi. The firewall on my pi allows connecting to those ports

I found something strange. My router shows a different external IP than curl https://ipinfo.io/ip and any other website for showing the IP. Using a website I get something like 83.xxx.xx.xx. That is the same address I get with every device in my network - how it should be.

my router shows an address like 100.xx.x.xxx

[my port forwarding settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qMVr.png)

I found no other way to get this ip-adress then in the router settings. It is a Fritzbox 7490. Might that be a issue of my router or the ISP? Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: I found something. Seems like a address beginning with 100.64.x.xxx indicates that my ISP is using a Carrier-grade NAT. So there is no solution to my problem I think?

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem just very recently with my ISP inexio.
As you stated in your answer your (and my) ISP uses CG-NAT to circumvent the lack of public IPv4 adresses.

The only solution to this is to either have your ISP forward your required ports for you (which they won't) or contact them to get a publicly routable IPv4 adress.
The latter costs me 1,50€ per month.

Please also note then in case you have anything to add to your initial question it is best practice on stackexchange to edit it with "EDIT: ..." instead of answering it.

Comment: I called my ISP and they gave me a public IP without problem in a few minutes. Needed way longer to understand what the problem has been.
I am new to stackexchange, but I see my answer already got converted to a comment. I didn't know about this convention.

Comment: I only discovered this by accident when I opened my Firtzbox's configuration page and did a lookup on the IP listed there. I tried to traceroute the IP and the software responded something along the lines of  "Adress in private adress space not routable". That's when I got curious and found out CG-NAT is a thing.